# Why empty array is getting initialized during the "for in " loop of javascript without assignment?

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

```js
var a=[],i=0,o={x:1,y:2,z:3}
for(a[i++] in o);
console.log(a);
```

output in Mozilla developer console : `Array [ "x", "y" ]`

I expect array to be empty as the loop never iterates. But it is                initialized with 'x' and 'y' .

What could be the reasonable explanation?

Comment: Why do you think “the loop never iterates”?

Comment: Isn't the output `["x","y","z"]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Your loop iterates three times (number of own keys of `o`). Both your expectation and your claimed observation are wrong. Output is `["x","y","z"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the loop never iterates

Yes, it does.

`for(key in o);` means *for each key as `key` of the object `o`*

Thus the loop iterates 3 times with 3 values `"x"`, `"y"` and `"z"`.

Then comes the trick that you can assign these values into the array by using the syntax `for(a[i++] in o);`.

Comment: Makes sense.  the key is assigned to a[i++] being an lval.

Answer (score 0):

The for...in statement iterates over all enumerable properties of an object that are keyed by strings.

```js
for (variable in object) {
  statement
}
```

> **variable**
> A different property name is assigned to the variable on each iteration.
>
> **object**
> Object whose non-Symbol enumerable properties are iterated over.

Comment: I suggest you to add a working example in you snippet